# How to override my plugin's php classes with duplicates that are in my child theme folder

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, jigoshop

I have a child theme in wordpress and one of the plugins I am using is called jigoshop.

I made a copy of a few php classes from the plugin and placed them in my child theme folder. I want these clases to override the ones from the plugin folder.

How would I go about doing that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you'll have to change the code where those classes are used which means that if you changed the class names in your copies then you have to replace the original names where objects are created. If you haven't changed the names you have to change the - paths of  include, require or whatever is used to include the class files - paths.

By the way - Merry Christmas! :)

Comment: @lgnas Where would I find the "paths of include, require or whatever is used to include the class files - paths"? I'm new to php, thanks!

Comment: I have no idea as I don't use wordpress, but I'm sure it's somewhere in one of the plugin files :)